# How to update laravel 8 to 9?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Here is my composer.json file. Whats line need to be updated ?
https://pastebin.pl/view/7e924024

thank you for help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Usually, frameworks like Laravel provide good tutorials for upgrades

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading Laravel requires a bit more steps then just updating composer, however they aren't too complicated.  Here is the guide along with all the steps:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#upgrade-9.0

To answer the question, for composer you would make the following changes (from the documentation):

> You should update the following dependencies in your application's `composer.json`file:
>
> - `laravel/framework` to `^9.0`
> - `nunomaduro/collision` to `^6.1`
>
> In addition, please replace `facade/ignition` with `"spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"` in your application's composer.json file.
>
> Furthermore, the following first-party packages have received new major releases to support Laravel 9.x. If applicable, you should read their individual upgrade guides before upgrading:
>
> - [Vonage Notification Channel (v3.0)](https://github.com/laravel/vonage-notification-channel/blob/3.x/UPGRADE.md) (Replaces Nexmo)
>
> Finally, examine any other third-party packages consumed by your application and verify you are using the proper version for Laravel 9 support.

**Note**: this will only upgrade composer, there are more changes that you should review in the documentation provided above so that you can fully upgrade to Laravel 9 correctly.